# how to obtain a 3d mask tensor from two given 2d mask tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

Given two 2d masks m1, m2 (both shape [m,m]), obtain 3d mask m3 (shape [m,m,m]):

> if m1[i][j] == True and m2[i][k] == True and i != j and i != k and j != k, then m3[i][j][k] = True

Note that m1 and m2 is diagonal, m1[i][j] = m1[j][i], m2[i][k]=m2[k][i]. but m3[i][k][j] is not necessarily True.

For example:

```
m1=[[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]]
m2=[[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]]
```

m3 (shape (3,3,3)) the only True value is m3[0][1][2]

Answer (score 0):

```
def _get_triplet_mask(mask1, mask2):
    indices_equal = tf.cast(tf.eye(tf.shape(mask1)[0]), tf.bool)
    indices_not_equal = ~indices_equal
    i_not_equal_j = tf.expand_dims(indices_not_equal, 2)
    i_not_equal_k = tf.expand_dims(indices_not_equal, 1)
    j_not_equal_k = tf.expand_dims(indices_not_equal, 0)
    distinct_indices = (i_not_equal_j & i_not_equal_k) & j_not_equal_k
    i_j = tf.expand_dims(mask1, 2)
    i_k = tf.expand_dims(mask2, 1)
    valid_labels = i_j & i_k
    return valid_labels & distinct_indices
```

modified from [sentence-transformers/sentence_transformers/losses/BatchHardTripletLoss.py](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/losses/BatchHardTripletLoss.py). in tensorflow